# why curl works but browser get 503 error?

Tags: google-chrome, http, nginx, curl

my web server use nginx and deployed vue project, it listened 80 port,  ip address is `172.10.2.200` when i use curl to visit my web site in my machine:

```
curl -i http://172.10.2.200
```

i can get it :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 03:12:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 4018
Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Aug 2022 00:22:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "62f2fa5a-fb2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"><title>title</title><link href="/js/chunk-0429ffa3.c3835ff0.js" rel="prefetch">
.... some elements
</body></html>
```

but when i visit it in chrome or other browsers, i get 503 error:

[image: screenshot]

and i tried postman, get same result:

[image: screenshot2]

my nginx config like this:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  60000;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length 10k;
    gzip_buffers 4 16k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_comp_level 5; 
    gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/css application/xml text/javascript application/x-httpd-php application/javascript application/json;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_vary on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        client_max_body_size 1024M;
    
        location / {
            root   D:\Path_To_Web\Web;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, the culprit is my proxy software,it intercepts my traffic, but doesn't know where this LAN address is